# How to turn my output from rows to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is the code I am trying to change to change:

```
date_data = np.array([[Qdate], [Ndate], [Vdate], [Tdate], [Sdate]])
```

Would anyone be able to help me turn it into columns? I have tried adding `.T` and `.transpose()` but these are just returning error messages. `Qdate` and all others are also `np.array`s.

`Qdate` is an `np.array` which was gathered by using `pandas` to read an excel file and it is all the dates in the data set. Date data needs to show all the dates of every state in a column coinciding to that state.

```
dfq = pd.read_csv('QLD.csv')
rawdata_q = np.array(dfq)
Qdate = np.array(rawdata_q[:,1], dtype = 'datetime64')
```

Comment: Tell us about `Qdate` (not just that its an array).  Also about `date_data` (e.g. `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: You have tagged `pandas` but this question does not appear to be about `pandas` are you trying to make a dataframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.